# Bearer oauth_problem="token_expired"

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, access-token, yahoo-oauth

I am trying to get the contact list from yahoo through `Yahoo OAuth 2.0 Authentication` I get the correct information of the user. But whenever I try to get the contacts list I get the error `token_expired`. This is the url that i use `https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/' + user.guid + '/contacts'` The guid is correct. My code is as follows:

```
app.get('/contacts', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.session.user) {
    return res.redirect('/auth/yahoo');
  }

  var user = req.session.user;
  var contactsApiUrl = 'https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/' + user.guid + '/contacts';

  console.log(user);
  var options = {
    url: contactsApiUrl,
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.accessToken },
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    json: true
  };

  request.get(options, function(err, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
    var contacts = body.contacts.contact.map(function(contact) {
      return contact.fields[0];
    });

    res.render('contacts', {
      title: 'Contacts',
      user: req.session.user,
      contacts: contacts
    });
  });
});
```

My app has permissions to:

1- Profile: Read/Write Public and Private

2- Contacts: Read

The access token should expire in 3600 seconds but it expires instantly.

I am using node.js (express.js) for this purpose.
I have searched this issue and many people suggested refreshing the access Token, but my app doesn't get the contact list even the first time I try to get it. So, I am guessing there is some other issue.
I know I haven't placed exception handling yet and app crashes when no information is received but that is not the issue here.